# iOS 7 - UIScrollView subView not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

Trying to add subviews to UIScrollView, which is defined in XIB file. The code below is how I tried to add subviews in my view controller. But no subviews were added.

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    CGRect frame = _tasksScrollView.frame;
    frame.size.width /= 3.0;

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blueColor],
                                                [UIColor redColor],
                                                [UIColor yellowColor],
                                                [UIColor greenColor],
                                                [UIColor purpleColor],
                                                nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [colors count]; i++, frame.origin.x += frame.size.width) {
        UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subView.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];

        [_tasksScrollView addSubview:subView];
    }

    _tasksScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width * [colors count], frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: you sure frame.origin.y is 0

Comment: It may be that your subviews are offset relative to the view space in your scroll view since youre carrying over the `x` and `y` coordinates from the `scrollview.frame` itself which is actually a position relative to the full screen. Try setting the `x` and `y` position of the subview so that it starts from `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My UIScrollView did not start at origin (0, 0) and I set my subviews frame's origin to be the same as UIScrollView's, which didn't work. Setting subview's origin to (0, 0) worked.

Comment: @bohanl I'm glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that your subviews are offset relative to the view space in your scroll view since youre carrying over the `x` and `y` coordinates from the `scrollview.frame` itself which is actually a position relative to the full screen. Try setting the `x` and `y` position of the subview so that it starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why this could happen, most of the time, you just fail to link/connect the  IBOutlet property (_tasksScrollView) in the XIB.